# Is there any way to display a message for when none of my if statements are true? (java)

Tags: java, if-statement

I have the following code block, and I want the program to print "My apologies, we do not have a sport suitable for you." if NONE of the if conditions are met. May I know if there is any way to do that with if statements? if not what should I do to make my program behave like that?

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

...

```
    System.out.println( "\n" );
    System.out.println("Please see below for suitable sport(s):");



    if ( age >= 18 && mVO2 >= 40 && mVO2 <= 60 && gender.equals("male") )
        System.out.println("Basketball");
    if ( age >= 18 && mVO2 >= 43 && mVO2 <= 60 && gender.equals("female") )
        System.out.println("Basketball");
    if ( age >= 18 && age <= 26 && mVO2 >= 62 && mVO2 <= 74 && gender.equals("male") )
        System.out.println("Bicycling");
    if ( age >= 18 && age <= 26 && mVO2 >= 47 && mVO2 <= 57 && gender.equals("female") )
        System.out.println("Bicycling");
    if ( age >= 18 && age <= 26 && mVO2 >= 55 && mVO2 <= 67 && gender.equals("male") )
        System.out.println("Canoeing");
    if ( age >= 18 && age <= 26 && mVO2 >= 47 && mVO2 <= 67 && gender.equals("female") )
        System.out.println("Canoeing");
    if ( age >= 18 && age <= 22 && mVO2 >= 52 && mVO2 <= 58 && gender.equals("male") )
        System.out.println("Gymnastics");
    if ( age >= 18 && age <= 22 && mVO2 >= 36 && mVO2 <= 50 && gender.equals("female") )
        System.out.println("Gymnastics");
    if ( age <= 25 && mVO2 >= 50 && mVO2 <= 70 && gender.equals("male") )
        System.out.println("Swimming");
    if ( age <= 25 && mVO2 >= 40 && mVO2 <= 60 && gender.equals("female") )
        System.out.println("Swimming");
```

Comment: use if else and else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work, according to your current code :

```
System.out.println( "\n" );
System.out.println("Please see below for suitable sport(s):");


boolean isAnyConditionTrue = false;

if ( age >= 18 && mVO2 >= 40 && mVO2 <= 60 && gender.equals("male") ){
    System.out.println("Basketball");
    isAnyConditionTrue = true;
}
if ( age >= 18 && mVO2 >= 43 && mVO2 <= 60 && gender.equals("female") ){
    System.out.println("Basketball");
    isAnyConditionTrue = true;
}
if ( age >= 18 && age <= 26 && mVO2 >= 62 && mVO2 <= 74 && gender.equals("male") ){
    System.out.println("Bicycling");
    
    isAnyConditionTrue = true;
}
if ( age >= 18 && age <= 26 && mVO2 >= 47 && mVO2 <= 57 && gender.equals("female") ){
    System.out.println("Bicycling");
    isAnyConditionTrue = true;
}
if ( age >= 18 && age <= 26 && mVO2 >= 55 && mVO2 <= 67 && gender.equals("male") ){
    System.out.println("Canoeing");
    isAnyConditionTrue = true;
}
if ( age >= 18 && age <= 26 && mVO2 >= 47 && mVO2 <= 67 && gender.equals("female") ){
    System.out.println("Canoeing");
    isAnyConditionTrue = true;
}
if ( age >= 18 && age <= 22 && mVO2 >= 52 && mVO2 <= 58 && gender.equals("male") ){
    System.out.println("Gymnastics");
    isAnyConditionTrue = true;
}
if ( age >= 18 && age <= 22 && mVO2 >= 36 && mVO2 <= 50 && gender.equals("female") ){
    System.out.println("Gymnastics");
    isAnyConditionTrue = true;
}
if ( age <= 25 && mVO2 >= 50 && mVO2 <= 70 && gender.equals("male") ){
    System.out.println("Swimming");
    isAnyConditionTrue = true;
}
if ( age <= 25 && mVO2 >= 40 && mVO2 <= 60 && gender.equals("female") ){
    System.out.println("Swimming");
    isAnyConditionTrue = true;
}



// THIS WILL BE FALSE IF IT DIDN'T GO INSIDE ANY BLOCK
if(!isAnyConditionTrue){
       System.out.println("My apologies, we do not have a sport suitable for you.");
    
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! this is what I am looking for.